# rspec2 throws 'undefined method' for model class method (.self)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have a model (event.rb) method, that retrieves a list of all recurrence dates for the named period

```
  def self.dates_between(start_date, end_date)
     dates = (start_date..end_date).step(7).to_a
  end
```

than I specify the following in event_spec.rb

```
  before(:each) do
    @event = FactoryGirl.create(:event)
  end    
  subject { @event }

  ... other working tests ...

  describe '#dates_between' do
    context 'finds recurrences dates of a event' do
      start_date = "2012-12-01 18:25:25"
      end_date = "2012-12-15 18:25:25"
      output_dates = ["2012-12-01 18:25:25", "2012-12-08 18:25:25", "2012-12-15 18:25:25"]

      it 'should call Event with method dates_between' do
        @event.should_receive(:dates_between).with(start_date, end_date)
        @event.dates_between(start_date, end_date)
      end

      it 'should find and return the RIGHT recurrences dates' do
        @event.dates_between(start_date, end_date).should eq(output_dates)
      end
    end
  end
```

and get this failure:

```
1) Event#dates_between finds recurrences dates of a event should find and return the RIGHT recurrences dates
 Failure/Error: @event.dates_between(start_date, end_date).should eq(output_dates)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `dates_between' for #<Event:0xb99e9f8>
 # ./spec/models/event_spec.rb:52:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

when I change in the model from a class method to an instance method (removing "self.") the console just prints out "wild data":

> 22:93:55", "2012-12-01 22:93:62", "2012-12-01 22:93:69", "2012-12-01
>   22:93:76", "2012-12-01 22:93:83", "2012-12-01 22:93:90", "2012-12-01
>   22:93:97", "2012-12-01 22:94:04", "2012-12-01 22:94:11", "2012-12-01
>   22:94:18", "2012-12-01 22:94:25", "2012-12-01 22:94:32", ...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it working, I made two faults:

- First, I needed to call on a class method (Event.dates_between) and not on an instance method (Event.new.dates_between)
- Second, I expected

  ["2012-12-01 18:25:25", "2012-12-08 18:25:25", "2012-12-15 18:25:25"]

but should have expexted without time, which screwed up my console by iterating through every second - minute - hour for the three expected days

```
["2012-12-01", "2012-12-08", "2012-12-15"]
```

No I do following and the specs are green:

```
describe Event do

  subject(:event) { FactoryGirl.create(:event) }

  describe '#dates_between' do
    context 'finds recurrences dates of a event' do
      start_date = "2012-12-01"
      end_date = "2012-12-15"
      output_dates = ["2012-12-01", "2012-12-08", "2012-12-15"]

      it 'should call dates_between with two arguments' do
        event.should_receive(:dates_between).with(start_date, end_date).and_return(output_dates)
        event.dates_between(start_date, end_date).should eq(output_dates)
      end

      it 'should find and return the RIGHT recurrences dates' do
        Event.dates_between(start_date, end_date).should eq(output_dates)
      end
    end
  end

end
```